# Project sdk 1.7 with Project language level 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

Is the following a valid combination:
Project SDK 1.7 with Project language level 8.

[image]

I keep hitting:

> Error:java: invalid source release: 1.8

But I don't want to delete my lambdas.

Comment: Well, you need the SDK 1.8 to use Java 8 (Seems logic). This could be warn by the IDE by the way

Comment: You can't use features that don't exist in the SDK. If you want lambdas to work, your SDK will have to be 1.8 as well. SDKs aren't forwards-compatible.

Comment: It baffles me that Intellij allows this.

Comment: Why the down vote? That intelliJ allows this is very confusing, so this is a fair question right?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why any IDE would let you choose such a combination (might be worth reporting a bug on it), as this is not a valid combination. You cannot use language features from a higher version than your SDK - the compiler just won't know how to treat the new syntax.